# Property value not updating post-edit of .plist file in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist, ios9

I am still receiving this error:

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."

Even though I have set the following in my .plist file:

[image: My .plist file]

I have seen in previous posts both on here and elsewhere that setting NSAppTransportSecurity -> NSAllowArbitraryLoads to YES is the solution but no luck.

I make the call in here:

```
/* Get user info */
                [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID]
                                                          completion:^(TWTRUser *user,
                                                                       NSError *error)
                 {
                     // handle the response or error
                     if (![error isEqual:nil]) {

//Data posted to 'http' here....                         
                         
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"Twitter error getting profile : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                     }
                 }];
```

If anyone can shed any light that would be appreciated.  Is there a way for me to check the value in the p.list at run time for example?

**EDIT 1**

[image: Edited value - No luck.]

Same error with above value in plist, also it doesn't seem this suggested value is valid?

Comment: Your first version was correct - it is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` although confusingly Xcode 7.1 now recognises these keys and displays nice descriptions as it does for "Bundle version" and this description uses the word "allow" instead of "allows".  Have you tried a clean build of your app?  Are you sure this is the info.plist that is being used?

Comment: That was it, I was editing the '-Tests' plist file instead, didn't notice I was in the wrong directory... Post as answer and I will mark correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version was correct - it is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` although confusingly Xcode 7.1 now recognises these keys and displays nice descriptions as it does for "Bundle version" and this description uses the word "allow" instead of "allows".

- Have you tried a clean build of your app?
- Are you sure this is the info.plist that is being used?